# Highlight results from an arrangedContent

Tags: ember.js

I'm "searching" (read filtering) some data with a input whos value is filtering an arrangedContent. Does anyone know/have an idea how I could highlight the letters being matched as I type?

I've included a JSBin to illustrate.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rojare/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to do this would be with an [Handlebars helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper)

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('highlight', function(value, options) {    
    var filter = options.hash.filter;
    var regex = new RegExp(filter, "gi");
    formattedTag = value.replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>");
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(formattedTag);
});
```

To make the whole thing to work, I changed a bit the model and the template, check out my version of your jsbin : [HERE](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/leweko/7/edit?html,js,output)